# How to check if a shared_ptr type is of <type> statically?

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, c++-concepts

I want to create a template container-class that should store instances
of `ABC`-derived classes.  With a constraint that only `ABC`-derived classes can use this template.

The container should be a static member of the derived class.

This is what I have now, though this won't work since `extendsABC` is not expecting a `shared_ptr`:

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

class ABC {
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
concept extendsABC = std::is_base_of<ABC, T>::value;

template <extendsABC T>
struct extendsABCStore {
  std::list<T> m_data;
};

struct Derived;

struct Derived : public ABC {
  void foo() override{};
  static extendsABCStore<std::shared_ptr<Derived>> instances;
};
```

[Build output](https://godbolt.org/z/rKnTeTf7W):

```
<source>:22:10: error: constraints not satisfied for class template 'extendsABCStore' [with T = std::shared_ptr<Derived>]
  static extendsABCStore < std::shared_ptr < Derived >> instances;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:13:12: note: because 'std::shared_ptr<Derived>' does not satisfy 'extendsABC'
template < extendsABC T >
           ^
<source>:11:24: note: because 'std::is_base_of<ABC, shared_ptr<Derived> >::value' evaluated to false
  concept extendsABC = std::is_base_of<ABC, T>::value;
                       ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: `std::is_base_of<ABC, std::decay_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>>::value`?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want `template < extendsABC T > struct extendsABCStore { std::list < std::shared_ptr<T> > m_data; };` or even simpler `using extendsABCStore = std::list<std::shared_ptr<ABC>>;`?

Comment: @Caleth 
Sure this is just a naive implementation.

Comment: How are you going to use this if you have both `extendsABCStore<Derived1> Derived1::instances` and `extendsABCStore<std::shared_ptr<Derived2>> Derived2::instances`? Much simpler would be pick one or the other.

Comment: @Jarod42 or `std::is_base_of<ABC, std::pointer_traits<T>::element_type>::value`

Comment: @Caleth I don't sure I understand. I want to access the classes instances from itself.

Comment: Yes, but do you want the instances by value, or the instances by (smart) pointer? Remembering that a copy is a different instance to the original

Comment: @Caleth instances should be referred in other classes as well so I chose shared_ptr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253586/discussion-between--and-caleth).

Comment: `template<typename T> concept extendsABC = requires (T t) { [](std::shared_ptr<ABC>){ }(t); }; ?`

Comment: Not relevant to your question but use derived_from (concept) or is_convertible (trait) rather than is_base_of for "extends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. Within the definition of `Derived`, it is an incomplete type, so `extendsABC<Derived>` is `false`. You also have a pointer where you want to constrain on the pointed-to type.

To fix the first, we can use a static member function rather than a static data member.

```
struct Derived : public ABC {
  void foo() override{};
  static auto& instances() {
    static extendsABCStore<Derived> store;
    return store;
  }
};
```

To fix the second, put `std::shared_ptr` in the definition of `extendsABCStore`

```
template <typename T>
struct extendsABCStore {
  std::list<std::shared_ptr<T>> m_data;
};
```

[Full example at godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/4WcbM975x)

Comment: [I can't get this working](https://godbolt.org/z/q6h4MGPf9) an I doing something wrong?

Comment: @ניר missing `()`, it's a function, not data

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not so much defining the concept. This can be done as

```
template<class T>
struct is_extendsABC : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_extendsABC<std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::bool_constant<std::is_base_of_v<ABC, T>> {};

template<typename T>
concept extendsABC = is_extendsABC<T>::value;
```

The problem here is that you're using a concept with a type (`Derived`) that is incomplete at the time of use (`instances` member declaration).

You could work around this by delaying the check of the type until `extendsABCStore` is specialized:

```
template <class T>
struct extendsABCStore {
    std::list<T> m_data;

    static_assert(extendsABC<T>, "T needs to be a std::shared_ptr with an element type derived from ABC");
};
```

[Godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:6,endLineNumber:38,positionColumn:6,positionLineNumber:38,selectionStartColumn:6,selectionStartLineNumber:38,startColumn:6,startLineNumber:38),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Clist%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%0Aclass+ABC+%7B%0A++++virtual+void+foo()+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate%3Cclass+T%3E%0Astruct+is_extendsABC+:+std::false_type+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Cclass+T%3E%0Astruct+is_extendsABC%3Cstd::shared_ptr%3CT%3E%3E+:+std::bool_constant%3Cstd::is_base_of_v%3CABC,+T%3E%3E+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aconcept+extendsABC+%3D+is_extendsABC%3CT%3E::value%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cclass+T%3E%0Astruct+extendsABCStore+%7B%0A++++std::list%3CT%3E+m_data%3B%0A%0A++++static_assert(extendsABC%3CT%3E,+%22T+needs+to+be+a+std::shared_ptr+with+an+element+type+derived+from+ABC%22)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Derived%3B%0A%0Astruct+Derived+:+public+ABC+%7B%0A++++void+foo()+override+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++static+extendsABCStore%3Cstd::shared_ptr%3CDerived%3E%3E+instances%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AextendsABCStore%3Cstd::shared_ptr%3CDerived%3E%3E+Derived::instances%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%23if+1%0A++++extendsABCStore%3Cint%3E+foo%3B%0A%23endif%0A++++//extendsABCStore%3Cstd::shared_ptr%3Cint%3E%3E+bar%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:gsnapshot,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:clang_trunk,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2B20%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/15%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to code a meta-function that takes a type `T`, and returns:

- `T` if `T` is not a `shared_ptr`
- The type pointed by the `shared_ptr` otherwise.

```
template<typename T>
struct remove_shared_ptr { using type = T; };
template<typename T>
struct remove_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>> { using type = T; };

template<typename T>
using remove_shared_ptr_t = typename remove_shared_ptr<T>::type;

// ...

template < typename T >
  concept extendsABC = std::is_base_of<ABC, remove_shared_ptr_t<T> >::value;
```

Comment: [Dosn't seem to work](http://tpcg.io/_1IL6T7)

Comment: @ניר when I press `Execute` i get an error for c++20 not enabled, though also does not work here with c++20 https://godbolt.org/z/9bWMd54f7

Comment: In the original example, `Derrived`  is incomplete when `instances` is defined, so that can't work (shared_ptr or not). Just define `instances` after `Derrived` is defined, as a regular global.

Comment: I can't  since I would need to name the containers as well, I use this in a generated code and this would introduce another complexity layer.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand the errors:

`std::shared_ptr<Derived>` is a smart pointer to the `Derived` class.

also `is_base_of trait` which you use in the `extendsABC` concept expects a class type.

However, I don't see a practical solution here. Seems impossible the way you try to implement it. Try creating a separate container class without tying it to any specific dirived class.

Answer (score 0):

Because concepts do not support template template parameters directly you can handle by introduce an extra layer of indirection using a helper type trait like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

class ABC {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
concept extendsABC = std::is_base_of<ABC, T>::value;

template <typename T>
struct TypeWrapper {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
using TypeWrapper_t = typename TypeWrapper<T>::type;

template <typename T>
struct extendsABCStore {
   std::list<T> m_data;
};

struct Derived;

struct Derived: public ABC {
    void foo() override {};
    static extendsABCStore<TypeWrapper_t<std::shared_ptr<Derived>>> instances;
};

extendsABCStore<TypeWrapper_t<std::shared_ptr<Derived>>> Derived::instances;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```